# Bind background color from colorpicker in typescript and angularjs1.5

Tags: angularjs, typescript, color-picker

I am trying to run Angularjs single page application (Ngroute).I want to set the selected color-picker color as a background to div. I am using Typescript with angularjs 1.5. My typescripte code is as follows.

```
let mainAngularModule = angular.module("acc-management", ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);
mainAngularModule.config(routeConfig);
routeConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

function routeConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/it', {
            templateUrl: 'linkmanager.html'
        })
        .when('/UserDefinedElement', {
            templateUrl: 'LinkType.html',
            controller: 'linktController as LTController'
        })
}
class LinkTypeController {
    private url: string;
    private token: string;
    public static $inject = ["$scope", '$http', '$q'];
    private TestString: any;
    public mycolor: string = "#f0f0f0";
    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService) {
    }
    public get Colortest() {
        return this.TestString;
    }
    public set Colortest(newItem: any) {
        this.TestString = newItem;
        alert('Layout is:');
        alert(this.TestString);
    }
    myStyle() {}
}
```

mainAngularModule.controller("linktController", LinkTypeController);

my html angular binding code is as follows.

```
<md-card-title>
    <md-card-title-text>

        <input type="color" ng-model="UDETController.mycolor" />
        <div ng-style="UDETController.divStyle">Testing for bachground color </div>
    </md-card-title-text>
</md-card-title>
```

I angularjs 1.5 we can use watch for it.but can we use similar functionaliyt like watch in typescipt so that my value form colorpicker is assigned to my div.